# Multiple headers with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Is it possible to pas multiple headers with AFNetworking?

I have this code:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {

self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

return self;
```

}

And I need to pass more header options such as "overrideauthentication = true" and a few others.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this with AFNetworking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `setDefaultHeader` as many times as you want with as many different `header`s and `value`s as you want. The headers can be standard `HTTP` headers or custom headers. `setDefaultHeader` may be a slightly misleading name in terms of multiplicity but think of it as setting multiple keys into a dictionary.